# React hook form - On Submit, Convert date object to string date in an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following data.

```
{
    status: "Reserved", 
    label: "Note", 
    title: "Login Fragment - Navigation component With Coroutine ", 
    shareWith: "", 
    notification_method: "Every Morning",
    notification_method_specific_time: Sat Jan 09 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time),
    noteDetails: Array(2)
        0:
            completed_date: ""
            description: "Test 1"
            due_date: Sat Jan 09 2021 20:00:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time) {}
            __proto__: Object
        1:
            completed_date: ""
            description: "Test 2"
            due_date: Sun Jan 10 2021 20:15:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time) {}
            __proto__: Object
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array(0)
    
}
```

The case is how to convert from Date format (object) to date string?

1. notification_method_specific_time
2. due_date: Sun Jan 10 2021 20:15:00 GMT+0700 (Western Indonesia Time) (in array)

My data is obtained from the onSubmit React Hook, and so far I have succeeded in point number one, as follows:

```
const convertDate = (date) => {
    return date ? moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm') : null;
}

const onSubmit = (data) => {
        
    const formData = {
        ...data,
        notification_method_specific_time: convertDate(data.notification_method_specific_time),
    }

    console.log(formData);
    // notification_method_specific_time: "2021-01-09 00:00"
        
}
```

But what about the date (due_date) element in the array, please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to map in your noteDetails and convert the `due_date`

```
const formData = {
    ...data,
    notification_method_specific_time: convertDate(data.notification_method_specific_time),
    noteDetails: data.noteDetails.map(note => ({
        ...note,
        due_date: convertDate(note.due_date)
    })
}
```